# Good open source computer vision software for C# (ASP.NET)?

Tags: open-source, library, computer-vision

I've already checked out EmguCV (built off of [OpenCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/OpenCV)).  EmguCV is relatively slow. Is there any other good open source computer vision ASP.NET (using C#)?  I'm primarily interested in object detection and facial recognition.  I want to be able to recognize common objects (ex. gallon of milk, computer screen, keys, etc).  Then identify where they are on the image.  It needs to run on Visual Studio 2013.  The software would have to be free.

Comment: What features should it have? Most programs so far were rather image processing, not really CV.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Sorry, I forgot to put that down.  I'm primarily interested in object detection and facial recognition.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add your requirements there? You might also wish to check [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) to see how you can attract more good answers ;) Thanks!

Comment: I suspect EmguCV is going to be your best option.